# San Francisco font in iOS 8

Tags: ios, fonts, ios8, ios9

I'm designing an app with the new SF fonts by Apple. To get the new SF fonts in the app, when building for iOS 9 you can just select "System font" in interface builder and it works. But the problem is that for earlier versions of iOS, the "System font" is actually Helvetica Neue, so that replaces San Francisco. How do I force San Francisco to show up on all devices?

Comment: You will need to supply the font with your app, but this will require a distribution license for the font. You will have to check whether you can get it for San Francisco.

Comment: Just reviewed the license: **3. No Transfer.** Except as otherwise set forth herein, you may not transfer this Apple Font without Apple’s express prior written approval. All components of the Apple Font are provided as part of a bundle and may not be separated from the bundle and distributed as standalone applications.

Comment: OK, tnx. Add this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is stated in the license agreement of the San Francisco font:

> **3. No Transfer.** Except as otherwise set forth herein, you may not transfer this Apple Font without Apple’s express prior written
>   approval. All components of the Apple Font are provided as part of a
>   bundle and may not be separated from the bundle and distributed as
>   standalone applications.